# Cannot play a relative mp4 video in a MediaElement WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to play a mp4 video in my media element in WPF.
The mp4 video is in a folder in my solution.
I tried diffrent things but the only way it works is when i put the full path to the video in the uri. 
 What am i doing wrong?

**XAML**

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoDice" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="VideoDice_MediaEnded" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

**C#**

```
VideoDice.Source = new Uri("DiceMovies/Dice_2.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
VideoDice.Height = 500;
VideoDice.Width = 500;
VideoDice.Play();
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648213/15019536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project for the `Dice_2.mp4` file it's necessary to set `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`. Looks like your `.mp4` file does not copied to the output directory automatically.